# Soket IO : emit to particular socket connection not to all connection

Tags: angular, socket.io

In my angular application I have Kafka consumer who emit all the messages to UI and its make UI very heavy to filter these message.

So when I connect through angular app I pass the filter in the parameter with socket IO connect. I receive that parameter on consumer side as well but problem is when second connection request come from other user with parameter then it consider that parameter instead of first one.

Following is my code

**Angular 4 service method** [ Client ]

```
getFeed(Ids: any) {
    const observable = new Observable(observer => {

    this.socket = io.connect('http://loclahost:3007', { query: 'Ids=' + Ids + '' });

    this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
    });
    return observable;
}
```

Kafka Consumer Code [ Server.js ]

```
'use strict';
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Kafka = require('no-kafka');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let techIds = [];

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("hello.");
});

//Socket IO Method
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('USER CONNECTED');
  this.techIds = socket.handshake.query['Ids'];
  console.log(this.techIds);

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   console.log('USER DISCONNECTED');
  });

});

http.listen(3007, () => {
  console.log('started on port 3007');
  var consumer = new Kafka.SimpleConsumer({
        connectionString: 'localhost:29092,localhost:29093,localhost:29094',
        clientId: 'no-kafka-client'
    });

    var dataHandler = function (messageSet, topic, partition) {
        messageSet.forEach((m) => {
            console.log(topic, partition, m.offset, m.message.value.toString('utf8'));
            if(topic=="MyMessage")
            {
                const msg = JSON.parse(m.message.value.toString('utf8'));
                if(this.techIds != null && this.techIds != undefined && this.techIds.indexOf(msg.techID.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                    io.emit('message', JSON.parse(m.message.value.toString('utf8')));
            }
        });
    }.bind(this);

    return consumer.init().then(function () {
        var v1= consumer.subscribe('JourneyDetails', [0, 1], dataHandler);
        var arr=[];
        arr.push([v1]);
        return arr;

    });
});
```

For example,

First User's socket connection request is http://localhost:3007?Ids=pm1,pm2,pm3

Second User's socket connection request is
http://localhost:3007?Ids=pm8,pm9,pm10

So in this line parameters value is overwritten by second request.

```
if(this.techIds != null && this.techIds != undefined && this.techIds.indexOf(msg.techID.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                    io.emit('message', JSON.parse(m.message.value.toString('utf8')));
```

Here I get this.techIds value "pm8,pm9,pm10" so in first request I get messages of pm8,pm9,pm10 instead of pm1,pm2,p3.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Pushkar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not happy with what I did as part of solution but something is running now.

Not happy because I am facing memory issue with client array. It becomes so heavy when more than 1000 users connected. My for loop takes too much time to filter the records.

Feel free to provide your suggestion/input to optimize below code.

```
'use strict';
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Kafka = require('no-kafka');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let techIds = [];

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("hello.");
});

//Socket IO Method
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('USER CONNECTED');

    socket.on('join', function (data) {
        clients.push(
            {
                'socketId': socket.id,
                'mgrId': data.mgrId,
                'techIds': data.attuIds
            });
        //console.log(socket.id + ' ' + data.mgrId + ' USER CONNECTED!!');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
        if (clients.length > 0) {
            let item = clients.find(x => x.socketId == socket.id);
            const index = clients.indexOf(item);
            if (index > -1) {
                //console.log(clients[index].mgrId + ' USER DISCONNECTED!!');
                clients.splice(index, 1);
                // console.log(clients);
            }
        }
    });

});

http.listen(3007, () => {
  console.log('started on port 3007');
  var consumer = new Kafka.SimpleConsumer({
        connectionString: 'localhost:29092,localhost:29093,localhost:29094',
        clientId: 'no-kafka-client'
    });

    var dataHandler = function (messageSet, topic, partition) {
        messageSet.forEach((m) => {
            console.log(topic, partition, m.offset, m.message.value.toString('utf8'));
            if(topic=="MyMessage")
            {
                const msg = JSON.parse(m.message.value.toString('utf8'));

                if (clients.length > 0) {
                    for (var index = 0; index < clients.length; index++) {
                        var ids = clients[index].techIds;
                        var idx = ids.indexOf(msg.techID.toLowerCase());

                        if (idx > -1) {
                            if (io.sockets.connected[clients[index].socketId]) {
                                io.sockets.connected[clients[index].socketId].emit('message', msg);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }.bind(this);

    return consumer.init().then(function () {
        var v1= consumer.subscribe('MyMessage', [0, 1], dataHandler);
        var arr=[];
        arr.push([v1]);
        return arr;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this article: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#

```
    io.on('connect', onConnect);

function onConnect(socket){

  // sending to the client
  socket.emit('hello', 'can you hear me?', 1, 2, 'abc');

  // sending to all clients except sender
  socket.broadcast.emit('broadcast', 'hello friends!');

  // sending to all clients in 'game' room except sender
  socket.to('game').emit('nice game', "let's play a game");

  // sending to all clients in 'game1' and/or in 'game2' room, except sender
  socket.to('game1').to('game2').emit('nice game', "let's play a game (too)");

  // sending to all clients in 'game' room, including sender
  io.in('game').emit('big-announcement', 'the game will start soon');

  // sending to all clients in namespace 'myNamespace', including sender
  io.of('myNamespace').emit('bigger-announcement', 'the tournament will start soon');

  // sending to individual socketid (private message)
  socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');

  // sending with acknowledgement
  socket.emit('question', 'do you think so?', function (answer) {});

  // sending without compression
  socket.compress(false).emit('uncompressed', "that's rough");

  // sending a message that might be dropped if the client is not ready to receive messages
  socket.volatile.emit('maybe', 'do you really need it?');

  // sending to all clients on this node (when using multiple nodes)
  io.local.emit('hi', 'my lovely babies');

};
```

Comment: Thank you for providing information. I have already gone through this cheatsheet. The challenge in my case is I want to filter the emit data based on the parameter which I receive from socket connection. Filter is also applied during emit but it apply to all other connection as well. I tried with socketid but no luck :(